# how to make an executable version of a WPF Kinect Application?

Tags: c#, wpf, exe, kinect

I have made a Kinect Application in Microsoft Visual Studio 2010. I need to make an exe of the application which can run on any windows based system. If I need to do that than is there any requirements that the system should fulfil? and If yes, then how do I do that?

I tried to use the exe in application/bin/debug/application.exe by copying it in another folder but it shows an error but if I run the exe from the bin/debug/application.exe it works. Am I missing something here or is it the only way to do that?

Comment: That means that there are DLL's in /bin/Debug that your app needs.

Answer (score 8):

"Any Windows based system" isn't going to work. Assuming you're using the Kinect SDK, it will only run on Windows 7 (and supposedly Windows Server 2008). The computer running the application will need either the Kinect Runtime, which only works with the new Kinect for Windows sensor, or the Kinect SDK, which also works with the Kinect for Xbox. Microsoft wants to sell more Kinect for Windows sensors, so they don't allow the runtime to work with the old Xbox Kinects. Makes sense in a way, but man that bugged me when I first found out about it. There's a [short post](http://channel9.msdn.com/coding4fun/kinect/When-deploying-Kinect-apps-ensure-the-runtime-components-and-device-are-ready) showing how to test for the existence of the Runtime on application load, so you can show an appropriate error message instead of just crashing out.

You need to copy any files that the program relies on, such as DLL files, along with the executable. There's instructions [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/microsoft_press/archive/2010/02/03/jeffrey-richter-excerpt-2-from-clr-via-c-third-edition.aspx) for how to embed the DLL files into the executable; I've not tried it but it might be worth a shot.

The correct .NET version should be installed when either the Runtime or the SDK is installed; you shouldn't have to worry about this.

Answer (score 3):

@Coeeffect is right, but you can also **publish** version 1.0.0.0 of your app by going to project -> properties -> publish -> publishing wizard to publish your application to then use on ther computes ect. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You need to copy all non-standard DLLs that your program uses.

The target computer needs the appropriate version of .Net.