# What are the minimum system requirements to run Kinect application's executable?

Tags: kinect, kinect-sdk, kinect-interaction

I am working on a Kinect application. I am planning on creating an executable for the application. The executable will then be installed on a "Windows Single Board Computers". Currently I am running the application on an i7 Desktop Tower with 3.4GHz and 8GB memory.

I have looked at the system requirements for Kinect SDK:
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44561
I think these specs are only when developing. But what would be the specs when I am only running the executable?

I looked at this question, [how to make an executable version of a WPF Kinect Application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11926654/how-to-make-an-executable-version-of-a-wpf-kinect-application)

To revise, I am going to program the Kinect on my Desktop tower. Create an executable for the application. Then install the application on the "Windows Single Board Computers" and then connect the connect to this new board and run the application.
What specs do I need for this "Windows Single Board Computer"?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a project called Virtual Dressing Room which engage some animations with Kinect data. To run only the Kinect data and play with it just needed 4gb ram with 1.9 Ghz CPU. But when it mixed with XNA animations then it required more ram like above 6GB. So it depends upon your application. If you simply play with kinect and 2D animations then 4GB ram is ok.
Since you are new to SOF I suggest if this answer can be acceptable then mark it. So you will have better responses for your future questions.

Comment: thank you for the help. have also used some alternative camera sensors? Because the main application is use estimate object, not people and their movement. could you suggest an alternate camera?

Comment: I'm afraid I've only used this camera.